# Custom indexOf without String methods

Tags: java, testing

I created my own `indexOf` function. I was wondering if anyone could help me come up with a way to make it more efficient. I am practicing for interviews so the catch is that I cannot use any String methods. I believe the runtime of this method is O(n^2) with space of O(n). Correct me if I am wrong.

Also, I want to ensure the program runs safely and correctly, the only test case I can think of it the length comparison.

code:

```
public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, char[] substr) {
    int len = str.length;
    int sublen = substr.length;
    int count = 0;
            if (sublen > len) {
                return -1;
            }
    for (int i = 0; i < len - sublen + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sublen; j++) {
            if (str[j+i] == substr[j]) {
                count++;
                if (count == sublen) {
                    return i;
                }
            } else {
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @Paul wow thanks! if only it was in Java....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try here for string searching algorithms:
http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/

And here for a way to test your implementation:
http://junit.org/

Comment: BTW.  Your algorithm is this one, I think: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node3.html#SECTION0030

Comment: Ignore the bit about "a more efficient algorithm in practice".  That's just using a C library function to make the (unchanged) algorithm faster.